# How can I code this indicator matrix without using a loop in R

Tags: r, for-loop, matrix, indicator

I have a vector of factors given by a sequence of numbers. These factors are also found in separate data seta, called `test_set` and `train_set`. What the following code does is find where the factor in the data sets matches in the vector of factors and puts a 1 in the place of the matrix. Multiplying this matrix `compound_test` by `test_set$Compound` should give you `compare_comp`.

```
test_set <- data.frame(Compound=letters[sample(1:3,10,replace = TRUE)])
train_set <- data.frame(Compound=letters[sample(1:3,10,replace = TRUE)])

compare_comp <- letters[1:3]
compound_test <- matrix(0,nrow(test_set),length(compare_comp)) # test indicator matrix
compound_train <-matrix(0,nrow(train_set),length(compare_comp))

for (i in 1:length(compare_comp)){
  compound_test[which(compare_comp[i]==test_set$Compound),i]=1
  compound_train[which(compare_comp[i]==train_set$Compound),i]=1}
```

Is there a function in R that lets me create the same thing without the need for a for loop? I have tried `model.matrix(~Compound,data=test_set)` but this does not include a column due to the reference level and also produces unwanted column names

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Easier option is `model.matrix` from `base R`

```
model.matrix(~ Compound-1, train_set)
model.matrix(~ Compound-1, test_set)
```

---

Or `table` can also be used if we `cbind` with a sequence of rows

```
table(cbind(nr = seq_len(nrow(train_set)), train_set))
```